# getting numbers out of sys.time

Tags: r, concatenation

is there a more efficient/elegant method of doing the following in which I concatenate all the numbers in the output of the `Sys.time()` output

```
x <- as.character(Sys.time())
paste0(substr(x,0,4),substr(x,6,7),substr(x,9,10),substr(x,12,13),substr(x,15,16),substr(x,18,20))
```

It probably includes paste and collapse somehow but not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have thought `format` to be the first choice:

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
[1] "20120909231732"
```

Comment: very good... thanks...though I'm not really sure what the difference is between the two?

Comment: `format` is a generic function. It examines the class of hte object and dispatches to a class-specific function, in this case, `format.POSIXct`. `strftime` on the other hand, is just a wrapper for `format.POSIXct`. I suppose an argument could be made for using `strftime` on the basis that its help page (shared with that of `strptime`) is where you find all the detail about the format string, but I think the more common choice by r-programmers would be to use `format`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `strftime()` to convert `POSIXct` object to character, using a format literal:

```
strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
[1] "20120910061602"
```

See `?strftime` for details on the string literals to use.

Comment: This is likely the preferred solution over `gsub` - you beat me to reading the help file for `?strftime`as I came back to edit my answer! It's likely faster too (?).

Comment: I keep forgetting about the strf type commands thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 4):

You could just strip non-numeric characters:

```
gsub("[^0-9]","",x)
[1] "20120910151242"
```

Comment: Was going to post `paste(unlist(strsplit(x, '[[:punct:] ]')),collapse = '')` as a solution, the above is far more straightforward